# How to copy a repository from Unfuddle to a local SVN server?

Tags: svn, version-control, unfuddle

I currently have a couple of SVN repositories hosted at Unfuddle and I'd like to have a local copy of the repositories as a backup. Ideally, it would be a "live" backup so my local repository would "ping" the remote repository, and if any changes were detected, the changes would be applied to my local repository.

Has anyone tried this before? If so, what tools were used to accomplish the job?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`svnsync`](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt), which creates a full mirror of the repository. `svnsync sync` will download only the new revisions. There's also a `svn-mirror`, which does the same thing.

Git's [`git-svn`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) is also an option.

I already used both `svnsync` and `git-svn`.

Answer (score 0):

I would just make a Scheduled Task that runs a PowerShell script/BAT file to execute a svn update for each of your repositories.

Answer (score 0):

To create a copy of your *repository* (ie: with all revisions intact), I think that you might have to do a full backup/download/restore cycle. There are ways to do an incremental copy of a repository (via `svnadmin dump` or `svnadmin hotcopy`), but I doubt that Unfuddle will give you access to these.